# How to marshall XML with namespace in JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I would like to marshal XML using defined XSD schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="myNamespace" xmlns="myNamespace">
    <xs:element name="element" type="JavaBean" />
    <xs:complexType name="JavaBean">
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

This is empty Java bean type:

```
package main;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "JavaBean")
public class JavaBean {
}
```

Simple test results in "**Cannot find the declaration of element 'element'.**" error.

```
package main;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;

import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, IOException, SAXException {
        final SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new File("sample.xsd"));

        JavaBean message = new JavaBean();
        JAXBElement<JavaBean> element = new JAXBElement<>(new QName("element"), JavaBean.class, message);

        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(JavaBean.class);
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        jaxbMarshaller.setSchema(schema);
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(element, System.out);
    }
}
```

What is interesting, when I remove targetNamespace and xmlns from XML Schema Definition, it works good.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can ignore namespace location while marshalling like jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION, "");

Comment: @Yogi I want to include it in resulting XML, not ignore it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your schema, the element is bound to the `myNamespace` namespace by default.

Thus you need to create `JavaBean` with the proper namespace:

```
JAXBElement<JavaBean> element = new JAXBElement<>(new QName("myNamespace", "element"), JavaBean.class, message);
```

Comment: Thank you. But isn't there anyway to tell marshaller to search for element in default namespace? So the program doesn't have to know about it.